# MS SQL, возможно ли конвертировать varbinarry в читабельный вид при получении данных из таблицы?

Tags: sql

Есть БД на MS SQL, в таблицу в определенное поле(тип varbinary(2000) пишутся данные в таком виде: 0x4500037F5D0E400080063EA40A281F1B0A28285CF64B05F2F25001562DE1FA0B501801FFB51C0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Можно ли, конвертнуть в читабельный вид ?

Comment: Ты хочешь, чтобы в твоя СУБД могла файлы всевозможного вида открывать? А если это игра D&nD?))

Comment: как вы себе это представляете? записано в поле у вас jpeg картинка, например,  какой вы ожидать будете там читабельный вид?

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. :)